# Better output with printf

Tags: java, printf

i have the following loop which print the first 1000 in arithmetic sequence . its works just the way i want to , but i have question could i use printf() instead of print() to adjust the output , because i dont see it neat and organize as i want.

Thank you in advance

```
public class Iteration /* Class name */
{
   public static void main(String[]args) /* main Method */
    {

      int s = 0;
      int sum = 1;
      while ( s < 1000 )

       {

         s++;
         System.out.print(" " + sum);
         sum += 3;
       }
```

Comment: And how do you want it to appear?

Comment: you could use `System.out.printf("sum = %d\n", sum);` or `System.out.println("sum = " + sum);` if that is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can. You can also use System.out.format

How? Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax